# Do I need a cryptographically secure random number?

Tags: cryptography, go

I'm writing a webservice in Go.

Upon login, the user is returned a token, which behaves roughly like a cookie in the sense that the user must pass it in each subsequent request in order to be recognized.

1. Does my token generator has to be "cryptographically secure", ie. generated with high entropy?
2. How can I achieve this in Go, preferably using standard libraries or libraries written by crypto-competent people unlike me?

Comment: We need more context to answer this question. Security is not absolute but a balance of tradeoffs.

Comment: @Fred I disagree. Something either is secure or isn't. The only exception is perhaps password hashing.

Comment: @ntoskrnl: You are wrong. Security is always a tradeoff. Even the notion of "secure" is a relative one.

Comment: @Volker What? A system either can be breached or it cannot. A secret is either secret or not. There is no intermediate. (Except perhaps with password hashes, as said.) Do not let physical lock or safe box analogies mislead you – cryptography is based on mathematics, not thickness of steel.

Comment: @ntoskrnl: So there are no secure systems as any system can be breached by the allen wrench/rubber hose method?

Comment: @Volker There are plenty of cryptographic systems which don't involve the human factor. TLS with an (EC)DHE ciphersuite comes to my mind as an example ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy)). But you are right, many systems indeed have that weak link. http://xkcd.com/538/

Comment: While security is often about trade-offs, in this case there is a simple, efficient and secure solution: `/dev/urandom` on Linux and `CryptGenRandom` on Windows. Exposed via `crypto/rand` in go. So I don't really see any useful trade-offs in the context of this question.

Comment: I don't think you need any special crypto functions other than hash function and some unique parameters (eg: SHA hash of a string based on user agent + ip address + etc)

Comment: @Brenden The problem with those values is that they're not secret. So you'd need to include a key in addition to them. That's certainly trickier than simply creating a random number.

Answer (score 5):

It would be beneficial for the token generator to be cryptographically secure, to reduce the ability of attackers to guess new session tokens and acquire the privileges along with them. [crypto/rand](http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rand/) implements such a random number generator, including functions that allow you to generate random integers, prime numbers and bytes suitable for this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use a crytographic hash. You can use something like gorilla/securecookie to generate a key and provide cookie storage: http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/securecookie

Note that if you are relying upon the cookie alone for verification that you open yourself up to replay attacks. Use the cookie to trigger a server-side check (user ID == active/valid) or bounce then out if the ID doesn't exist.